# iTunes connect says 'Invalid Binary' although I have 'NSCameraUsageDescription' property in my info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, build, binary, app-store-connect

In my app users have to have an access to the Camera or CameraRoll and I do have NSCameraUsageDescription property in my info.plist

[image: Property in info.plist]

and yet when I upload the build to the app store I get an automatic response saying the following

[image: Response from Apple Review Team]

What should I do now? I have uploaded 3 builds but all of them have been rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` also in your `info.plist` same as you are adding `Privacy - Camera Usage Description`.